# Show new navigation once user log in?

Tags: users, navigation

I'm building a site using Drupal 7 and have a question regarding navigation and roles. My site requires that a lot of content be accessible only to members. I'm wondering how I can show a secondary navigation element on the site once a user logs in? Obviously this would be tied to an authenticated user role.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can try [Menu per role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module to hide the links

Answer (score 1):

This module might do the trick:

http://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility

I've not installed it myself, but it seems to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth mentioning that in Drupal, if you don't have access to view a node, then you won't see the link to that node if it's in a menu.

So I think you first need to find a node access control module. Something like [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) which is based on [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl) module.

Then you need to add those nodes as a menu item into your menu. If people don't have access to any of the nodes on that menu, then that menu will not show anything.

Comment: This looks like just what I need. In your opinion, would using the beta version of this (7.x-1.2-beta1) be a safe bet on a production site?'

Comment: I can't say for sure, as it's different from module to module. What I usually do is quickly scan through the issue queue for the version you want to download, see if any glaring broken issues affect it. Also check how many sites installed this module in the "Usage statistics". (15,127 as of May 27th 2012 for Content Access module 7.12-beta) Anything over 2 to 3 thousand usage is safe bet I'd say.

Comment: You can help them release a stable version too should you wish: **"We are working hard to release the stable Drupal 7 version of Content Access, please help test the current version, and report any bug on the issue queue."**  ^^